# Delayed promise data with SveteKit

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I need to get a list of files name from firestore storage api

```
async function gcsFilesList(uid: string): Writable<T> {
   let ret: string[] = []
   let store = writable(ret);
   if (browser) {
    const storage = firestorage();
    
    const listRef = ref(storage, `gs://bucket_name/folder_name`);

    listAll(listRef)
        .then((res) => {
            res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
                listAll(folderRef).then(subRes => {
                    subRes.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
                        if (itemRef.fullPath.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                            ret.push(itemRef.fullPath)
                            console.log("store item", ret)
                        }
                    });
                })
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("list error", error)
        });
   }
   return store
}

export const filesList = gcsFilesList
```

In +page.ts I am calling this function

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export async function load({ params }: { params: any }) {
    let ret = {
        data: getWork(params.id),
        files: filesList(params.id)
    };
    return ret
}
```

And in +page.svelte I consume this data

```js
onMount(async () => {
        filesData = data.files;
}
```

```svelte
{#await filesData}
  <p>...waiting</p>
{:then files}
  <p>list of files {files}</p>
{:catch error}
  <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
.
.
//OR
{#if $filesData != null}
  {#each $filesData as pfds}
  <p>{pfds}</p>
  {/each}
{/if}
```

In any way the rendered list is empty and after seconds I see that the object the function returned (ret) is getting filled with data. but this data is not rendered in the HTML.

What I need to do in order to render the data when it comes.

Comment: Have you read [the docs on this](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises)?